# Dipole moment and polarity of borazine / borazole / inorganic benzene

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, polarity, dipole, pnictogen, boron-family

What is the dipole moment of borazine? I tried googling it but can't find a reliable source. I searched in JD Lee too. It might have it but I could not find.

Answer (score 5):

[This NIST publication](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/NSRDS/nbsnsrds10.pdf) lists the dipole moment as zero, while [drugfuture.com](http://www.drugfuture.com/chemdata/borazine.html) (I've never heard of this site) reports a value of 0.50 as measured in benzene at $\pu{25^oC}$.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest, but not complete, way to tell if the dipole is zero or not is look for a centre of inversion, which borazine would have if it were flat like benzene.

To be absolutely certain  the molecule's point group has to be found. To have a dipole the molecule must belong to $C_1, C_{nv}, (n>1) $ and $C_s$ point groups.

As borazine is not planar (according to wikipedia page) and seems to belong to $C_{3v}$ so it should have a dipole. However, looking at the structure the dipole has to be small due to the way the atoms are arranges around the 3 fold axis and the small displacement of the plane containing the B to that of the N atoms. If you can find B-N, N-H, B-H bond dipole  values you could calculate the dipole, at least get an approximate value.

Comment: If I remember correct, [borazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borazine) is planar $D_\mathrm{3h}$?

Comment: @orthocresol yes $D_{3h} $if planar and so no dipole.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: This is just an effort not complete answer. I also request higher members to give answer / put bounty as this question is not having complete answers.

Borazine is planar. But the borazine ring does not form a perfect hexagon. The bond angle is $117.1°$ at the boron atoms and $122.9°$ at the nitrogen atoms, giving the molecule distinct symmetry.

Dipole moments are forming exact $120°$ with each other resulting in net non zero dipole moment and polar molecule.With support of comments I calculated
[image]

[image]

Borazine, also known as borazole, is a polar inorganic compound. 3D model : https://chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/jmol.php?model=%5BBH-%5D1-%5BNH%2B%5D%3D%5BBH-%5D-%5BNH%2B%5D%3D%5BBH-%5D-%5BNH%2B%5D%3D1

All details are from Wikipedia.

Comment: According to your structure Borazine has point group D3h. Hence it has no dipole moment. See https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Symmetry_(Vallance)/01%3A_Chapters/1.04%3A_Symmetry_and_Physical_Properties

Comment: Also it would be good to reference where you got the above structure from (and picture if you didn't draw it yourself), I'm guessing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borazine

Comment: The issue with Borazine is whether it is *flat*. If it is, it can't have a net dipole. If it isn't flat (and you can't tell that from the picture above) and the borons are on a different plane to the nitrogens (ie the molecule is puckered) then it *inevitably* has a dipole but it will be *perpendicular* to the ring.

Comment: @matt_black I agree with you but source tell what i mentioned.

Comment: @Jay Your answer clearly doesn't agree. The problem is your assumption that the issue is whether the bonds in borazine need to be exactly 120°. Even if they are not, the molecule would not have a net dipole since it still has enough symmetry for the net bon dipoles to cancel. **Only** if it is non-planar is this not true.

Comment: @matt_black I understood that but this efforts will help in further answers i think. So, i don't think it is appropriate to delete till you insist. What shall I do further delete or not?

Comment: @matt_black Note the interior angles sum to 720, as in any planar, not necessarily regular, hexagon. (e.g. https://www.coolmath.com/reference/polygons-06-hexagons). When I first wrote my first comment I thought this was enough to state that this means the given structure is planar, though on rethinking the logic that's not true - it does not necessarily follow from "the sum of angles in all planar hexagons is 720" that " if the sum of angles in a hexagon is 720 it is planar". But I will be amazed if it is not so ...